# Max Array Sum failing for some test cases

Tags: python

So first thing I am not giving any test. Just practicing for competitive coding. I was solving this question from Hacker Earth.

[Given an array of integers, find the subset of non-adjacent elements with the maximum sum. Calculate the sum of that subset.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/max-array-sum/problem)

I tried solving first using dynamic programming approach. Here's what I wrote:

```
def maxSubsetSum(arr):
if(len(arr)>2):
    #mainting this array for storing intermediate result and last element of this will always be max sum
    li=[0]*len(arr)
    li[0]=arr[0]
    li[1]=arr[1] if arr[1]>li[0] else li[0]
    for i in range(2,len(arr)):
        li[i] = max(li[i-1],arr[i]+li[i-2])
    return li[len(arr)-1]
else:
    return max(arr)
```

But unfortunately, 7 of the cases are failing out of 33 and its not because of timeout but wrong answer. I can't think of any problem in my code.
I used some hackos to get the one of hidden test cases. PFB the test case, its quite huge so uploading to pastebin

https://pastebin.com/GrM4gFJF

Just want to know what's wrong in the code because of which some test cases are failing

Comment: Didn't use the test cases (haven't used pastebin) but by removing the `range(2,len(..))` to `range(len(..))` give me the correct results for the test cases inside the first link. Did you tried without the `2`?

Comment: yes, it worked but why ? I mean ideally I have already calculated the result for 0th and 1st index so I have started the loop from 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ( to answer you comment) but look at the extended run of the for loop.
You store in li the first two values (according `li[1]=arr[1] if arr[1]>li[0] else li[0]`) and in the loop you perform calculation based on the first two values of the list `(l[i-2])` which is subtracted (see loops 2,4) result in "full" is result in `range(2` -2 (which is l[0).

```
used list [-2, 1, 3, -4, 5]
entering the for loop(full range)
loop number 0
intervals li[i-1]=0 : li=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] : arr[i]=-2 : li[i-2]=0 : arr[i]+li[i-2]=-2 
loop number 1
intervals li[i-1]=0 : li=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] : arr[i]=1 : li[i-2]=0 : arr[i]+li[i-2]=1 
loop number 2
intervals li[i-1]=1 : li=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0] : arr[i]=3 : li[i-2]=0 : arr[i]+li[i-2]=3 
loop number 3
intervals li[i-1]=3 : li=[0, 1, 3, 0, 0] : arr[i]=-4 : li[i-2]=1 : arr[i]+li[i-2]=-3 
loop number 4
intervals li[i-1]=3 : li=[0, 1, 3, 3, 0] : arr[i]=5 : li[i-2]=3 : arr[i]+li[i-2]=8 
final li=[0, 1, 3, 3, 8]
8
----------
used list [-2, 1, 3, -4, 5]
entering the for loop (2,x)
loop number 2
intervals li[i-1]=1 : li=[-2, 1, 0, 0, 0] : arr[i]=3 : li[i-2]=-2 : arr[i]+li[i-2]=1 
loop number 3
intervals li[i-1]=1 : li=[-2, 1, 1, 0, 0] : arr[i]=-4 : li[i-2]=1 : arr[i]+li[i-2]=-3 
loop number 4
intervals li[i-1]=1 : li=[-2, 1, 1, 1, 0] : arr[i]=5 : li[i-2]=1 : arr[i]+li[i-2]=6 
final li=[-2, 1, 1, 1, 6]
6
```

This making the initial calc of the 0th and 1st sum unnecessary.Try it.

Hope it helps and somewhat shed more light :)

Suggested final code:

```
def maxSubsetSum(arr):
  if(len(arr)>2):
        #mainting this array for storing intermediate result and last element of this will always be max sum
        li=[0]*len(arr)

        for i in range(len(arr)):
            li[i] = max(li[i-1],arr[i]+li[i-2])

        return li[len(arr)-1]
  else:
      return max(arr)
```